# htaccess for root pages / but not sub-directories or sub-domains

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

trying to rewrite URL strings only for pages that reside in the root, removing the page extension for cosmetic reaons.  For example:

www.site.com/page.html  ==>  www.site.com/page
www.site.com/about.html ==> www.site.com/about

Using this code currently:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+\.com) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

BUT, I don't want the rule to modify sub-directiories or sub-domains.  For example I also have:

clientA.site.com (which is mapped to www.site.com/clientA), which I need to not be remain unchanged.  Right now it is sending that page (client.site.com/index.html) to a page not found.

Answer (score 0):

Your rule doesn't affect subdomains. There must be other rules causing the `404` not found response.

If you want to restrict requests to the root pages, you can specify that with an appropriate pattern by excluding slashes in the request URL path

```
# exclude directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# allow top level request URLs only
RewriteRule ^[^/]*$ http://www.%1/$0 [R,L]
```

*Never* test with `301` enabled, see this answer
[Tips for debugging .htaccess rewrite rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542)
for details.